# MOSFET not driving a relay

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, relay, opto-isolator, esp32

I've been trying to drive a 24 V SMD relay with an internal coil resistance of 2880 Ω and an isolated 3.3 V logic input.

I selected the 2N7002 MOSFET (Ic=115 mA) to drive the relay; the relay needs 24/2880=8 mA to energize and it seems no problem to drive it with this MOSFET.

I made a test circuit using the following schematic but the test shows the relay is not activated.

[image]

I updated the schematic with both an N- and a P-FET as well as a PNP and an NPN BJT.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you mean to pull the relay when you don't apply voltage to the 3.3_logic input? Does the LED light up?

Comment: Part number for the relay is a 12 V relay. Is that what you are actually using or something else?

Comment: You are pulling the gate up to 24 V, it is specified for 20 continuous at most. Does the relay change state when you put a 100 Ohms resistor from D1 to COM?

Comment: It looks more like the relay will never turn **off**.

Comment: logic LED works fine with a low-frequency pulse, but LED on the relay side just works once, the actual relay is the 24-volt rate, I put the R1 pull-down for not activate  the relay on  MCU  reset, but I think I should put a pull-down resistor on U4 MOSFET, however, if I put pull-down resistor not sure to turn off MOSFET whenever has no signal

Comment: I’m concerned that the sum of forward voltages of the opto led and LED1 are too high for a 3.3V drive.

Comment: @Bryan forward voltages drop or sinking current from MCU pin

Comment: @Hamidsk the current is probably fine, though you should check. But the typical forward voltages of the opto and even a red LED get close to adding up to 3.3V or more and the LEDs may not conduct, or the current may be too low to effectively excite the phototransistor in the opto coupler. Check the voltages with your multimeter.

Comment: Adding 4 circuits makes it harder to relate comments and answers to the actual circuit. Why not focus on just one? Please add the part number of the additional LED on the coupler input. side.

Answer (score 6):

The opto-coupler is driving the FET incorrectly. The configuration shown below will work.

Be certain the current through the opto-coupler is within the specification. Make \$R_1=R_2\$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYmw2um.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Update: The [data sheet for the optocoupler](https://www.digikey.com/htmldatasheets/production/9798/0/0/1/pc817x-series.html?utm_adgroup=xGeneral&utm_term=) shows that the diode forward voltage can be as high as 1.4 V.
[image]
A red LED has a forward voltage of at least 2.1 V. The total voltage required to reliably turn on the opto-coupler in series with a red led is at least 3.5V. Blue and green LEDs require about 3.6 V. I have updated the circuit diagram to show a better way to provide input indication. Choose \$R_3\$ for the brightness. Choose \$R_4\$ to saturate the transistor when 3.3V is applied. Use the current transfer ratio diagram in Figure 6 of the data sheet to assist.
[image]

**Another Option:** Based on the data sheet ratings, the opto-coupler should be able to drive the relay directly.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect too, that LED1 is dropping too much voltage to allow the opto-coupler LED to turn on.  What you could do is bypass LED1 and re-connect LED1 by itself and its own series limiting resistor to the 3.3 V input signal.
Then, both the opto and LED1 will get enough voltage and current to turn on.

I also suspect the load resistance of around 600 Ω gives a high-enough current where the opto might not have enough gain to turn the opto-coupler off. You don't need such a low resistance for that FET gate. Try 10 kΩ or so, no need for the lower resistor

Also, 24 V on the gate may be a bit high for that FET.

Comment: my FET configuration was a mistake, I update the schematic with new designs